# Access SSIS OLEDB Command Output parameter?

Tags: sql, ssis, dataflow

I have created SSIS package to update invoice details.
In my oledbcommand control in 'data flow' tab execute sp using

```
exec ? = spInsertInvoice ?,?,?,?,?,?
```

this sp returns a single row with last inserted id, my question is how do i assign this row values to an variable (or is there anyway to access return values)